# Which sentence is better? Is present perfect needed to say that something happened only once?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

> Once I have seen a little boy about 5-7 years old taking a grandmother
> across the street alone!
>
> Once I saw a little boy of 5-7 years old moving his grandmother across
> the road alone!

Which sentence is better? Is present perfect needed to say that something happened only once? I know that Americans are inclined to use past simple where others would use present perfect, so it's optional for Americans either to use present perfect or past simple.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is correct.  The first is not.

You could say

> I have seen a little boy of about 5-7 years of age taking a grandmother across the street alone!

but not

> Once, I have seen...

There is a tense clash there because the "have seen..." indicates an action or condition that was ongoing in the past, but "Once" indicates an timeframe at a specific instant, which was not ongoing.

Also, we would not say the boy was "alone" - he was with the grandmother.  "All by himself" is better:

> I once saw a little boy, no more than five or seven years old, helping his grandmother to cross the road all by himself!

^ this is more natural English than either of the above.

Answer (score 1):

"Once I saw..." is correct, because the word "once" fixes the experience as a single event in the past. "I have seen..." is a statement about your history of seeing things that is still true.
The phrase "moving his grandmother" sounds strange. It should be taking, or even better, guiding.